# Como guardar todos los resultados que arroje un SELECT en una variable para después usarlo en otra consulta

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Tengo una consulta SELECT. El caso es que me tiene que devolver varios datos. Cuando lo imprimo dentro del while si me imprime ambos, pero si lo imprimo después solo guarda el primero. Me gustaría saber como podría guardas ambos en la misma variable con una sola consulta, para así poder usarla en otra consulta mysql. Muchas gracias de antemano.
PD: he probado colocar la siguiente consulta dentro del while pero sigue sin funcionar.
El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM cookies_grupos WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $gruposcookies = $mostrar['grupo'];
    //Este echo si que me imprime todos los datos
    echo $gruposcookies; ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo = '".$gruposcookies."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1"; 
  //Sin embargo este no, solo devuelve el primero.
  echo $gruposcookies;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $publicacion=$mostrar['publicacion'];}?>
```

Comment: limit 1, solo devuelve 1 registro, debes quitarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo lo que sucede es que el segundo  echo $gruposcookies; lo estas mostrando por fuera del ciclo while, donde quieras llamarlo debes recorrerlo de nuevo para que te muestre todos los resultados. Algo asi:

```
<?php $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM cookies_grupos WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $gruposcookies = $mostrar['grupo'];
    //Este echo si que me imprime todos los datos
    echo $gruposcookies; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo = '".$gruposcookies."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1"; 
    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $gruposcookies = $mostrar['grupo'];
    //Este echo si que me imprime todos los datos
    echo $gruposcookies; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $publicacion=$mostrar['publicacion'];}?>
```

Recuerda que las variables de las consultas tengan nombre unico para que evites errores yo les coloque un 1 al final. Y como consejo yo utilizaría mejor un foreach para mostrar los datos en vez de un while.

Comment: Díaz y en la segunda consulta en el where podría me saldrían ambos datos?